# Passing hex strings to Radare2

Tags: radare2, hex

I can quickly test hex string arguments in `gdb` like this:

```
r $'\x61\x61\x61\x61'
```

I'd like to do something similar in `radare2` but all I can figure out is regular strings:

```
doo aaaa
```

I tried this but the argument isn't interpreted as a hex string

```
doo $'\x61\x61\x61\x61'
```

How can I format a hex string argument and pass it to `doo`?

Answer (score 1):

There most be a better way than the one I going to show you but this is how I do it:

I make a rarun2 profile. I'm going to call it "tmp.rr2" and it will contain this:

```
 #!/usr/bin/rarun2
 arg1=\x6f\x60\x72\x72\x76\x6e
```

Note: arguments from arg1..arg[N]

Then in the command line type:

```
 $ r2 -r tmp.rr2 -d crackme02
```

Note: You can update the file and run `ood`/`doo`

UPDATE:
I found a better way so you don't have to make a rarun2 profile: 
Run r2 as normal and type:

```
> dor arg1=\x6f\x60\x72\x72\x76\x6e
> doo
```

Comment: +1. the `rarun2` profile works! the `dor` + `doo` combo isn't working for me.